May the King execute by a method other than decapitation today?
Rambam says in Melakim uMilkhamot:
וְאֵין לַמֶּלֶךְ רְשׁוּת לַהֲרֹג אֶלָּא בְּסַיִף בִּלְבַד
The King may only execute by sword
What's the source for Rambam's codification? Does this hold today?

"Does this hold today?" We don't have a king today...

The source for the rambam is the Yerusalmi in Sanhedrin , beginning of the 7th Perek

הלכה: אַרְבַּע מִיתוֹת נִמְסְרוּ לְבֵית דִּין כול׳. וְלָרָשׁוּת לֹא נִיתַּן אֶלָּא דִין הֶרֶג בִּלְבַד
Four kinds of execution was the court empowered to impose,” etc. But to the government only decapitation was given.

The Mareh Panim explains that this is the source of the Rambam.

ולרשות לא ניתן אלא דין הרג בלבד. תוספתא בשלהי פ"ט ארבע מיתות נמסרו לבית דין סקילה שריפה הרג וחנק הרשות לא ניתן לה אלא סייף בלבד. מכאן למד הרמב"ם ז"ל לומר כן בפ' י"ד מסנהדרין הלכה ב' וכן בהלכות מלכים פ"ג הלכה א' ואין רשות למלך להרוג באחת מהן אלא בסייף בלבד והמפרשים לא ציינו מקומו

Another source is the Tosefta Sanhedrin 9:3.
(Found these sources in the commentaries to The Rambam - Tziyunei Maharn and Mekorei Rambam Lerashash , available on Sefariah)
As to your question "does this hold today"
רמב"ם מלכים א’ הלכה ד

אין מעמידין מלך בתחילה אלא על פי בית דין של שבעים ואחד זקנים ועל פי נביא כיהושע שמינהו משה רבינו ובית דינו וכשאול ודוד שמינם שמואל הרמתי ובית דינו

הלכה ז

ומאחר שמושחין המלך, הרי זה זוכה לו ולבניו עד עולם, שהמלכות ירושה, שנאמר (דברים יז): "למען יאריך ימים על ממלכתו הוא ובניו בקרב ישראל".

Loosely translated and explained, Rambam rules that in order to appoint a King you need Sanhedrin and a prophet.
Once a King like that was appointed, his son will inherit the kingdom without that.
Hence, it will be quite impossible to appoint a King these days and as such this halacha does not apply these days.

"Loosely translated and explained, Rambam rules that in order to appoint a King you need Sanhedrin and a prophet." According to some understandings of the Rambam it is still possible to appoint a king without a prophet when there are no prophets known. That aside, the point remains, we simply do not have a king today so the question is moot.

Are you implying that there's never been a Jewish king besides Moshiach? My question is about the Laws of Kings, not specifically exclusively Moshiach. Why did you jump to Moshiach?
Only a small fraction of the Jewish Kings across history had any relationship with the Sanhedrin over the short period which is existed.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143559/how-did-the-kingdom-of-ofran-come-to-be
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143624/contact-between-kings-of-simien-and-the-sanhedrin?noredirect=1#comment479566_143624
