Did the Kings of Simien ever try to reach out to the Sanhedrin once it was finally formed?
Is there any record of contact between the Sanhedrin and the Kings of Simien?
If not how did the Kingdom of Simien function without contact?
Did they continue to mashacht kings without contact?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Simien

The first paragraph of the linked Wikipedia entry states that Simien: "refers to a legendary Jewish kingdom... first mentioned by the traveller Benjamin of Tudela in the 12th century CE"

Short answer to the first question: No. And I don't understand the second question. The only kings who need anointing post-the destruction of the Kingdom of Israel are the kings of Beit David.

My understanding is that there are Danite, Kohanic, and Davidic lineages in the region who warred frequently.

I'm sorry, maybe the question should be "Did the King of Simien ever try to reach out to the Sanhedrin once it was finally formed?" .. however many centuries later.

Whatever the question, we don't know. We have little information regarding the Jews of Ethiopia in antiquity.

We do not know such a kingdom to have actually existed other than in legend. And the earliest records of such a legend are from many centuries after the Sanhedrin was disbanded. How is this a reasonable question?

@Deuteronomy If what you say is true, then answering the question "is there any record of contact" should be straightforward. The rest is probably unanswerable.

@magicker72 an answer about the lack of correspondence between the Sanhedrin and the kings of Narnia would also be straightforward... and should also be unnecessary.
